# How to extract rows in Pandas based different criteria over two datetime columns

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, jupyter

My objective is to calculate the number of firemen working simultaneously during the same period of time.

I'm trying to extract rows from a dataframe with conditions on two columns but It doesn't work as expected.

Let me explain

Here are my data firt (this is the list of firemen interventions) with the number of firemen and start and end of the intervention.

| ID | Nombre d'agents (Engins) | Date Début Sortie Engin | Date Fin Sortie Engin |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 194683 | 3.0 | 2018-03-01 19:12:00 | 2018-03-01 19:54:00 |
| 194684 | 3.0 | 2018-03-01 19:20:00 | 2018-03-01 20:09:00 |
| 194685 | 3.0 | 2018-03-01 19:33:00 | 2018-03-01 20:16:00 |
| 194686 | 3.0 | 2018-03-01 19:50:00 | 2018-03-01 23:01:00 |
| 194687 | 3.0 | 2018-03-01 19:53:00 | 2018-03-01 20:20:00 |
| 194688 | 3.0 | 2018-03-01 19:54:00 | 2018-03-01 20:55:00 |
| 194689 | 3.0 | 2018-03-01 19:56:00 | 2018-03-01 21:20:00 |
| 194690 | 6.0 | 2018-03-01 20:03:00 | 2018-03-01 22:10:00 |
| 194691 | 3.0 | 2018-03-01 20:09:00 | 2018-03-01 20:54:00 |

Here is what I'm trying to achieve:
Between 2018-03-01 19:20:00 and 2018-03-01 19:54:00 : 12 firemens were working during in the same time for a cumulated 1h34. (3 from first row 19:20->19:54 (34mn) and 3 from second row 19:20->19:54 (34mn), 3 from third row 19:33->19:54 (21), 3 from fourth row 19:50->19:54 (4mn) and 3 from fifth row 19:53->19:54 (1mn))

I first combined all datetime (start and end) chronologically in a dataframe in order to have all timeslot and timedelta between rows.

```
data = [df["Date Début Sortie Engin"]]
headers = ["Moment"]
df3 = pd.concat(data, axis=1, keys=headers)
data = [df["Date Fin Sortie Engin"]]
df4 = pd.concat(data, axis=1, keys=headers)
df3 = df3.append(df4)
df3 = df3.sort_values(by="Moment", ascending=True)
```

| Moment |
| --- |
| 2018-03-01 19:12:00 |
| 2018-03-01 19:20:00 |
| 2018-03-01 19:33:00 |
| 2018-03-01 19:50:00 |
| 2018-03-01 19:54:00 |

I then compare two consecutive rows of this new dataframe to my initial datas to find out how many interventions include this timeframe. I sum the number the number of firemen and the number of simultaneous event

```
def calc_effectif(start, end):
    mask = (df['Date Début Sortie Engin'] >= start) & (df['Date Fin Sortie Engin'] <= end)
    return df['Nombre d\'agents (Engins)'].loc[mask].sum(), df['Nombre d\'agents (Engins)'].loc[mask].count()

df3["effectif"],df3["evenement"] = np.vectorize(calc_effectif)(df3["Moment"], df3["Moment"].shift(-1))
```

the mask doesn't seem to be the right way to do that. I've look into pandas between_times and other function but it works on index only... so I'm a bit stuck for now.

Any tip on how I can make progress on this ?

Comment: What is your expected output? Just the first two rows are enough.

Comment: expected output is a pivot table with number of firemen/time spent/number of simultaneous interventions

Comment: Yes, we all got that. The question was more a numerical expectation.

Comment: thanks, I actually solved my problem, the condition in my function with not right. Correct condition was: mask = (df['Date Début Intervention (JJ/MM/AAAA HH:MM)'] <= start) & (end <= df['Date Fin Intervention (JJ/MM/AAAA HH:MM)'])

Comment: Tu pourrais en fait poster ta solution pour 1) Ques nous puissions avoir un equivalent dans des situations differentes 2) afin de pouvoir obtenir des réputaions pour ton travail. :-)

Answer (score 0):

so, I solved my problem by changing the condition in my function:
`mask = (df['Début Sortie Engin'] <= start) & (end <= df['Fin Sortie Engin'])`

I end up with something like this :

| Id | Moment | duree | effectif | evenement |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 01/03/2018 19:12 | 00:08:00 | 3.0 | 1 |
| 1 | 01/03/2018 19:20 | 00:13:00 | 6.0 | 2 |
| 2 | 01/03/2018 19:33 | 00:17:00 | 9.0 | 3 |
| 3 | 01/03/2018 19:50 | 00:03:00 | 12.0 | 4 |
| 4 | 01/03/2018 19:53 | 00:01:00 | 15.0 | 5 |
| 5 | 01/03/2018 19:54 | 00:00:00 | 18.0 | 6 |
| 0 | 01/03/2018 19:54 | 00:02:00 | 15.0 | 5 |
| 6 | 01/03/2018 19:56 | 00:07:00 | 18.0 | 6 |
| 7 | 01/03/2018 20:03 | 00:06:00 | 24.0 | 7 |
| 1 | 01/03/2018 20:09 | 00:00:00 | 27.0 | 8 |
| 8 | 01/03/2018 20:09 | 00:07:00 | 24.0 | 7 |
| 2 | 01/03/2018 20:16 | 00:04:00 | 21.0 | 6 |
| 4 | 01/03/2018 20:20 | 00:34:00 | 18.0 | 5 |
| 8 | 01/03/2018 20:54 | 00:01:00 | 15.0 | 4 |
| 5 | 01/03/2018 20:55 | 00:25:00 | 12.0 | 3 |